# ¿Cómo dar formato a la fecha de los mensajes del log?

Tags: java, kotlin, logger, slf4j

Tengo un programa hecho en Kotlin que usa `LoggerFactory` de la api slf4j para guardar registro de la actividad en la salida estándar. El código se ve algo como esto (simplificado para quedarme sólo con lo básico):

```
package miPackage

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

class TestLog {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestLog::class.java)
      log.info("Arrancando app...")
    }
  }
}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto obtengo lo siguiente en la salida estándar:

> 2018-02-05 11:08:37.516 [main] INFO miPackage.TestLog - Arrancando app...

Lo cual es correcto, pero me gustaría saber si es posible darle formato a esa salida del log. En particular a la fecha, a la que me gustaría añadir la zona horaria. Es decir, en lugar de obtener `2018-02-05 11:08:37.516` me gustaría que fuera algo como `2018-02-05 11:08:37 -0500` (los milisegundos pueden o no estar presentes).

¿Es eso posible? ¿Cómo se haría?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea un fichero `logback.xml`, en `src/main/resources` si usas maven, y configura ahí la salida del log. Por ejemplo:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss -SSS} %-5level %logger.%method:%line - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

[Aquí](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) tienes más información sobre Patterns.

Comment: Parece más simple que las otras cosas que he probado. Voy a añadirlo a mi código y comento.

Comment: ¡Funciona! Lo único: cambia el `-SSS` por un `-ZZ` al final de la cadena, de lo contrario parece que lo que se muestran son los milisegundos y no la zona horaria que es lo que quiera. Pero aparte de eso, funciona perfectamente. Gracias.

Comment: Vale, pensaba que eran los milisegundos, sí.